# onChange and onClick inside a button doesn't work on I.E

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, button, input

React: 16.

`onClick` in input field and `onChange` doesn't work on `IE`. It works smoothly on chrome.

Is adding two `onclick` causing this issue ? One on button and another on input field ?

```
<button onClick={this.addEventOnTimePicker()}>
  <div style={style.buttonContent}>
    <div style={style.buttonIcon}>
      <Clock style={style.iconStyle} />
    </div>
    <input
      style={style.timeInput}
      onClick={() => {
        this.timePickerToggle(!open);
      }}
      disabled={disabled}
      ref={instance => (this.dropDown = instance)}
      value={typeof time === 'string' ? time : moment(time).format('LT')}
      onChange={this.onTimeChange.bind(this)}
    ></input>
  </div>
</button>
```

```
timePickerToggle = open => {
  this.addEventOnTimePicker();
  this.setState({ open }, () => {
      ....
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Hi Check out this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41901997/12037439) you're going to need a pollyfill if you do not have one, and [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8877) is a more detailed explanation

Comment: There are two things, onClick and input field. 
If onClicks fails then, at least Input field should work but none of them are working on I.E

Comment: Hi so you have the pollyfill installed?, since your still using onClick within the input tag, does the onChange on the inputfield work

Comment: Yes just installed it, still it doesn't work. Mouse cursor changes like an input. No onChange is not working.

Comment: Let me check it out for a sec on IE. and see if i can help

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Comment: I have been playing around with the code snippet inside IE and the onclick, has been working with the current structure of your code, what i did not pick up until now is that you have an input tag inside a button tag

Comment: After removing <button it is working.

Comment: yeah hope you pick up that it will trigger the outter onCick , when you click on the inner onClick

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206044/discussion-between-vikas95prasad-and-rawk).

Answer (score 3):

Final Working code on IE:

```
<div
  style={style.buttonContent}
  onClick={() => {
    this.timePickerToggle(!open);
  }}
>
  <div style={style.timeIcon}>
    <Clock style={style.iconStyle} />
  </div>
  <input
    style={style.timeInput}
    disabled={disabled}
    ref={instance => (this.dropDown = instance)}
    value={typeof time === 'string' ? time : moment(time).format('LT')}
    onChange={this.onTimeChange.bind(this)}
  ></input>
</div>
```

Comment: Congratulation. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.